# Exits while loop before condition is false?

Tags: c++, while-loop

This is a pretty specific question but my program seems to exiting its while loop before the condition is false. I added in quite a few memory checks for safety when I was debugging and it prints to screen that counter is 4 and SqRoot is 6 at the end which means it should still be looping through (TestNum=32). I definitely know it's getting past the loop with counter<=SqRoot because it prints both "The integer 32 is composite" and "The integer 32 is prime". Any help is very appreciated! Thanks so much

EDIT: I changed the overall logic of program and it is working now. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Declare variables.
int TestNum, DivInt, SqRoot, PrintCounter(0), oppcounter;
float DivFloat, counter(2);

int main()
{
//Prompt user for input.
cout << "Input an positive integer to test its primality.";
cin >> TestNum;

//Check if input is positive.
while (TestNum < 0)
{
    cout << "Please input a *positive* integer.";
    cin >> TestNum;
}

//Square root.
SqRoot = sqrt(TestNum)+1;

//Loop to test if prime.
while (counter<=SqRoot)
{
    ++counter;
    DivFloat = TestNum/counter;
    DivInt = TestNum/counter;
    oppcounter = TestNum/counter;
    if (DivFloat-DivInt == 0)
    {
        ++PrintCounter;
        if (PrintCounter==1)
        {
        cout << "The integer " << TestNum << " is composite.\n " \
                << TestNum << " is divisible by\n";
        };

        cout << counter << "  " << oppcounter;

        cout << "counter* " << counter;
        cout << " TestNum " << TestNum;
        cout << " DivInt " << DivInt;
        cout << " SqRoot " << SqRoot;
        cout << " DivFloat " << DivFloat;
    }
}

if (counter<=SqRoot)
{
    cout << "The integer " << TestNum << " is prime.\n";
}

cout << "counter " << counter;
cout << " TestNum " << TestNum;
cout << " DivInt " << DivInt;
cout << " SqRoot " << SqRoot;
cout << " DivFloat " << DivFloat;

//End main.
return (0);
}
```

Comment: It prints variables in if. It is just not entering it anymore, but loop continues.

Comment: I thought that originally but I added that asterisk to "counter" inside the if and it's the final check that is printing. Plus it's printing both "the integer 32 is composite" and "the integer 32 is prime", so it gets past the loop with counter<=SqRoot.

Comment: Works completely fine at my end (for that specific testcase)! What is the exact error you are getting? Only thing I see is you are missing a `}` for `main()`

Comment: @binaryBaBa The problem was it was printing both "The integer 32 is composite" and "The integer 32 is prime." The `if (counter<=SqRoot)` was a check on the loop that added. Once it makes it out of the while loop, counter<=SqRoot should be false and "The integer 32 is prime" shouldn't print, but it does. I have an addition check at the end, and counter=4 while SqRoot=6 when the program ends.

Comment: Perhaps your system is getting a rounding error. If you're going to use `++` for loop counter then the variable should be an integer, not `float`. I'd suggest changing `counter` to `int`, and `SqRoot` to be `double SqRoot = sqrt(TestNum)+0.5;`  - then you avoid any rounding issues with being close to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing the opposite behavior of what you are describing, and I can see why. It's possible that the code you have posted is different than the code you are executing.

As an aside, I added the line

```
cout << endl;
```

after the line

```
cout << " DivFloat " << DivFloat;
```

at couple of places to make the output more readable.

When I enter 32, I see the following output:

```
The integer 32 is composite.
 32 is divisible by
4  8
counter* 4 TestNum 32 DivInt 8 SqRoot 6 DivFloat 8
counter 7 TestNum 32 DivInt 4 SqRoot 6 DivFloat 4.57143
```

When I enter `17`, I see the following output:

```
counter 6 TestNum 17 DivInt 2 SqRoot 5 DivFloat 2.83333
```

The reasons for that:

1. You don't break out of the `while` loop when you have detected that a number is a composite.
2. As a result of that, you always break out of the `while` loop only when `counter<=SqRoot` evaluates to false. As a result, in the code below,

   ```
   if (counter<=SqRoot)
   {
      cout << "The integer " << TestNum << " is prime.\n";
   }
   ```

you never execute the line in the `if` block.

The program should behave correctly if you break out of the `while` loop when you detect a composite and change the logic in the last `if` block to:

```
if (counter > SqRoot)
{
   cout << "The integer " << TestNum << " is prime.\n";
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see that I have the wrong condition in that final if. But, my output printed both "The integer 32 is composite" and "The integer 32 is prime."

Comment: Exiting the `while` loop when you detect a composite should fix it.

Comment: I wanted to list all the factors too, which means I have to go through the loop all the way, so that's why I wasn't just using `break;`.

Comment: In that case, you can use the value of `PrintCounter`. If it is `0`, it's a prime otherwise it is a composite.

Answer (score -2):

Why so strange check for prime?

```
for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; ++i)
{
     if (n % i == 0)
     {
          cout << "not prime";
          break;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Never done one before. I was trying to figure out the logic on my own and ended up on a weird path. Now I can't figure out why it doesn't work